# Multiple Button using click binding, only one gets wired up

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In the context of a `ko foreach: widgits` I am building list items with a few buttons that expose options to the user.

```
<ul>
<!-- ko foreach: wigits -->
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: $data.text"></span>
        <button id="fast" data-bind="click: function(){$root.spinWidget($data, '1000rpm')}"></button>
        <button id="medium" data-bind="click: function(){$root.spinWidget($data, '500rpm')}"></button>
        <button id="slow" data-bind="click: function(){$root.spinWidget($data, '200rpm')}"></button>
    </li>
<!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

When I click the first button I see the click handler is invoked each click.  When I click or inspect the other buttons i see that no click handler is setup.

Comment: Give some working code that you have tried(fiddle).

Comment: Can you please modify my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mYVvz/1/ and try to reproduce your issue there and post the updated fiddle? Because based on the info in your question your code should work fine now...

Comment: i'm not able to reproduce this in fiddle, however that made me realize there must be some error that's happening i'm not seeing.  I found a place where we were eating errors... now i have found what appears to be a bug in knockout's interactions with jquery.  I'm editing my post to include the stack trace and error info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem ended up being that i had included knockoutjs below jquery, once i moved it above, it works.  idk why but it does.